# Facebook user_photo permission not granted to other users

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3

Good Day!,

I making an iOS App that required user_photos from Facebook. So i used the Facebook API. My problem is not all the user has a permission for user_photos

Example

User 1

```
"permissions": {
    "data": [
      {
        "permission": "user_birthday",
        "status": "granted"
      },
      {
        "permission": "user_photos",
        "status": "granted"
      },
      {
        "permission": "user_about_me",
        "status": "granted"
      },
      {
        "permission": "email",
        "status": "granted"
      },
      {
        "permission": "publish_actions",
        "status": "granted"
      },
      {
        "permission": "public_profile",
        "status": "granted"
      }
    ]
  }
```

User 2 has only public_profile Permission

```
permissions =     {
        data =         (
                        {
                permission = "public_profile";
                status = granted;
            }
        );
    };
```

How can i make user_photos permission applicable to all user?

Thanks i hope you can help me for this one.

Comment: Did Facebook approve you to use user_photos permission? And did you ask the user to grant you user_photos permission?

Comment: @WizKid the user_photo permission is still in review in Facebook... But why the other faceboook account user_photo is granted?

Comment: Anyone that has a role on the app you can ask any permission even if it is not approved by Facebook